# Calculate simple NPN transistor circuit Arduino 3.3V

Tags: arduino, transistors, relay, latch

I am trying to control a 3v latching relay (single coil) using an Arduino @ 3.3v [SPST-NO PCB Mount Latching Relay, 16 A, 3V dc] rs-online.com/web/p/latching-relays/8276283/
  The relay requires a 3v positive to latch one way, and inverse to latch the other way.

I think this is the circuit I need to implement:

[image]

However, I cant get the relay to switch because the voltages in the coil are not high enough (should be 3v and I am getting +-0.49V when using 3.3v supply). 
(using transistors: BC558 and also tried BC548) 
(relay coil Coil Resistance: 16.8ohm)

I have done a simulation using livewire which shows pretty close what I am measuring in real live.
[image]
I have been suggested to use an H-bridge, however I would like to know if having a 5V supply, I can make this circuit work and make the design simpler.

Could I get some help on how to make this work and understand it?

I have set variable resistors in the simulator and tried different values but cant get 3V.

Comment: Redraw your circuit a bit simpler: Leave the "off" tranny out, replace the "on" tranny by wire, replace the solenoid by something like 10Ω resistance and then calculate a bit what currents are flowing where.

Comment: voltage is probably not high enough because of the 47R resistors. If you make them smaller and do the corrections Plasma suggested you will find out why a H bridge was recommended

Comment: ok, I am working on it. Thank you. It is looking good. I will post soon...

Comment: i got I relay activation. then voltage levels are still too low. my intention is to have this relay turn on/off a 230V appliance by an arduino. I want to prevent having to supply current to a regular relay constantly.

Comment: transistors are heating up and I cant manage to get enough voltage for the relay to switch. Is it at all possible or should I stop trying?

Comment: it seems there have been other similar attempts http://www.thebackshed.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=7402&PN=15&TPN=2

Comment: Your attempt to use a resistor against a transistor is fundamentally impractical.  You need an H-bridge to achieve your goal of bidirectional drive from a single supply.  At 3.3v that should be a MOSFET bridge - if you want to use a bipolar transistor one like an L293D (popular but not recommended) you would probably have to raise the supply voltage to meet minimums and account for losses.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I am convinced now that the BJT approach is not the best. I am going to look for a h-bridge to achive what I need. I have seen the L9110S is quite popular and after looking into it, its seems a very simple implementation also. Thank you for your time

Comment: Now you know why they make 2 coil latching relays .If you must use your single coil and dont want to do a H bridge try a half bridge and a capacitor .

Comment: I learned the lesson. I just couldn't find any 16A latching relay for 3V in farnell or rsonline, any suggestion? Regarding your suggestion, could you elaborate a bit? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just 2 transistors will work, but you'll waste a significant amount of current from the power supply.

The reason you can't get enough V across the relay coil is that its resistance is much lower than the 47 ohm resistors -- they limit the current too much.

If the relay really requires 3 V, and is 16 ohm, you'd need to make the 47 ohm something like 1.6 ohm or lower in order to allow 3 V across the resistor. Now, the 'ON' transistor will need to sink both the relay coil current and the supply across the 1.6 ohm -- 2 A !

That would require a base current of ~ 100 mA which an Arduino won't be able to supply...

Using 5 V makes things easier, but not very practical yet -- you can use about 10 ohm, so the transistor currents become about 500 mA instead of 2 A

Best solution is to use an H-bridge -- replace each 47R with a PNP transistors shown here.

Your circuit (as you show) will also need clamp diodes -- else the back emf from the relay coil will cause large + spikes and damage the NPNs the 1st time you turn off the NPNs.

You can use MOSFETs instead of the NPNs and PNPs -- for Q1 & Q2, then you don't need R1, R3. For Q3, Q4, you don't need R2 & R4.

This circuit should work for 3 or 5 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZFe2q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much jp314! I have learn quite a bit with your explanation and as I wrote above, I am convinced now that I MUST use h-bridge. I have seen L9110S is quite popular so will look for that. I assume I need a low power one. Any recommendation on an IC is welcome. Thank you for your great answer.